LogOff script runs with administrator privileges?
I have a script that I'm trying to bring to the desired result. it runs when the user logs off, during which the onedrive process should start, I expect it to run as the user, which ends the session, but when displayed interactively, I see a notification that onedrive cannot be started as an administrator. the user does not have administrator privileges.

Export the task scheduler job to xml and use pastebin or some free service so I can see how the task scheduled job is configured. Seeing the script logic would be helpful too for seeing exactly what you are working it. With more detail and a ping back, I may be able to give other pointers or ideas.

TLDR; You should consider locking the user session instead of logging out so the OneDrive app continues running as the previously logged on user.
This will not work as you are attempting to start a service as a user during the log off process. I assume that you want to do this so the OneDrive app continues to sync data for that user even after they logout. There is no supported way to do this as part of a log off workflow since the OneDrive app needs to run as the specific user (since there can be multiple users on a single computer each with different OneDrive synchronized folders).

my script edits attributes on files in the current user's onedrive directory, so that these files are processed by onedrive and free up space on the physical disk. This script works fine in a regular scheduled session, but the goal is to trigger a logout, the script works, but at the time of its operation the Onedrive client has already terminated, restarting the Onedrive process within the script has elevated privileges.

Why not have your script make the changes while the user is logged in, check the status of the changes and then log out?

The idea is that the user logs in to the system and works with documents without obstacles and unnecessary re-uploads to the computer, but after rebooting or logging out of the system his locally located Onedrive files free up disk space.

When running my script at logout onedrive processes are already finished, I manually start them from the default location, but in the interactive mode of this script I see that on logout onedrive is running and waiting for account login, so there is a dependency on some other service? I tried to start services related to microsoft passport but it did not solve the problem. Any ideas why at this stage may not log in to the current user account in the ondrive client?
